# Incorrect colors while drawing lines on android

Tags: android, canvas, drawing

I try to draw 10 lines using overrided method onDraw and this code:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        canvas.drawLine(0,100*i,canvas.getWidth(),100*i,paint);
    }

}
```

In result i get lines with different opacity. I don't know what reason of these transormations.
[image: screenshot]
I use genymotion emu with android 5.1 and api 22

Comment: check it on real device some times genymotion does not show correct line pixel..

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It really helps

Comment: vote up my comment it may help others too!